# IBM Domino - internet sites + substitution with '?' in incoming rule errors

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

For upcomming larger Xpages project we need to use substitution rules to provide SEO friendly URLs. We need to define rules similar to this one:

```
Incoming URL pattern: /*/products?*
Replacement pattern: /web.nsf/view.xsp?lang=*&*
```

This substitution  should work with URL e.g.:

```
/cz/products?start=1&count=20
```

and substitute to

```
/web.nsf/view.xsp?lang=cz&start=1&count=20
```

But we just found out that when incoming rule contains '?' it simply returns Error 404 . We found this reported here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/a8162420467d5b45852576c7007fc045?OpenDocument.
Is there any workaround or fix for this situation ? Documentation doesnt mention such limitation ... which is, in fact, very significant because we are not able to redefine the rule to fit our (very common) situation.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can solve that issue easily.

If you can't find an easy solution I would suggest you to look on these 2 approaches:

1. You build DSAPI filter and define your custom substitutions there (that way speed won't be affected).
2. You point requests to single xsp and that xsp will check incoming requests and redirect them to appropriate place (based on your custom substitutions).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at your poject here https://github.com/dpastov/domino-dsapi-handler ... but its C based and we need Windows version for production servers and Linux one for development ... I would rather try to avoid this

Comment: Than try to figure out if point 2 is acceptable for u.
What about one more server in front of Domino? Is it an option?

Comment: I just realized that I can probably avoid ? at all and make URL something like: /cz/products/start=1&count=20  and then adjust Incoming URL pattern to  /*/products/*